# Is the pinyin for 他撇了撇嘴 actually "tā piē le piězuǐ" (as given by Pleco)? And if so, why are the two 撇s pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin

There are two pronunciations for [撇](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%92%87): piē and piě.  As I understand, the pinyin for [撇嘴](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%92%87%E5%98%B4) is piě​zuǐ​.  But then I see this example sentence on Pleco...

> [image: Pleco example sentence]
>
> 他撇了撇嘴，轻蔑地一笑。
> **Tā piēle piězuǐ.**
> His lips curled in a contemptuous smile (or a sneer).

I'm puzzled as to why the pinyin on the first 撇 is given as piē (1st tone) above.  My understanding is that this is an example of verb reduplication, so the two 撇s are the same, in which case I would expect their pronunciation to be the same.  So...

**Question**: Is the pinyin for 他撇了撇嘴 actually "tā piē le piězuǐ" (as given by Pleco)?  And if so, why are the two 撇s pronounced differently?

Comment: I pronounce it as "tā piě le piězuǐ" in day to day usage.

Comment: Judging by the responses, it looks like this is an error. Someone should file a report to Pleco for them to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `撇` is pronounced as `piē` when it means 'to cast away' (as in `撇下兒女`) or 'to scoop off' (as in `撇油`). Note it is a verb in both cases.
2. `撇` is pronounced as `piě` when it means 'left-downward stroke' (as a noun in `撇捺`), 'to throw (horizontally)' (as in `撇磚頭`), or 'to incline' (outwards, as in `八字腳向外撇`). `撇嘴` literally means to incline the ends of the lips downwards, usually to express discontent; so it must be pronounced in the third tone.
3. I suspect Pleco detected the first `撇` as a verb, then jumped to the conclusion it should be pronounced in the first tone. It failed to realise `撇` here is a detached verb and is collocated with `嘴`. After tone sandhi `撇了撇嘴` should be pronounced like `3023`.

[image]

Reference: 余培英（2012）《多音字學習手冊》。北京：商務。